# meteor.js and npm require fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, fs

I am confused, i need to use fs package for meteor.js fw.

From meteor version 0.6> i need to use Npm.require like this:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

But when i do it an error appear:  npm is not defined

How to solve it? I tried mrt add npm but hm...

BTW: i have /root/packages/npm

**EDIT**
My code was in the both client/server side folder so i moved it to the block for a server as

```
var fs;
if(Meteor.isServer) {
  fs = Meteor.require('fs');
}

fs.writeFile(path + name,...

GETTING ERROR: Cannot call a method writeFile of undefined
```

**SOLVED**
Well i solved the error by wraping the whole content to the Meteor.isServer {... but if someoen could explain to me from curiosity why it does not work like above?

Comment: Could you run mrt --version and check your meteor version?

Comment: additional question for you: are you trying to use Npm server or client side? (you can just use it server side)

Comment: I had run mrt --version before i posted question. It was 0.6.4 i guess. And in collections folder i am not sure what side it is?

Comment: Code outside Meteor.isServer block gets executed also on the client, and since 'fs' isn't defined there it throws error.

Answer (score 2):

It's `Npm`, not `npm`, and in your question you use both. Javascript is case-sensitive, make sure you use the proper `Npm` form.

Comment: I think the OP refers to this: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#what-about-npm-node-modules

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `package.js` in your app or a smart package that explicitly specifies the dependency via `Npm.depends` before you can use `Npm.require`. You don't need the `Npm.depends` or a smart package if you are using a built-in `npm` package such as `fs`, but you still need to make sure you are using it on the server-side and not the client side.

For an example, check out the `package.js` file for my Meteor package that pulls in ShareJS:
https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs/blob/master/sharejs-ace/package.js

See also this post:
http://shiggyenterprises.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/accessing-the-file-system-in-meteor/

Comment: Thx for reply, i have seen the post before but i dont know what to do with it. BTW: my require is in /collections folder. Inside Meteor.methods({ // probably server side?

Answer (score 0):

Not to detract, but... Another option you might want to use is the Meteor file structure itself. You could bypass NPM and use your **Assets** in Meteor. In Meteor, things in your private folder can be accessed by something like `var data = Assets.getText("example.txt").toString().split("\n");` for example, if you wanted to turn a document into an array of word. That's just an example. I'm not sure exactly what you need to do. :)

Answer (score -1):

Since "fs" is part of node, you can simply do: 
`var fs = Meteor.require('fs');`

Comment: I tried it before, now again and get error: object object has no method require.

Comment: That's odd. I just tried on a brand new project and it works.
What I did was `mrt add npm` followed by `mrt` to run the server and to install the required npms and it worked.

Comment: And where you put the code? I have it in the /collections folder

Comment: I don't use SO that often and I'm not sure how to see notifications, but you would normally put it in server only code. fs cannot be used client side.